# MSSQL incorrect charset in php arrays

Tags: php, arrays, sql-server, laravel, freetds

Need to create connect to mssql from ubuntu with php(laravel). I'm using freetds and sybase mssql adapter for it. Successfully connected to base and can select data from it. But, when i'm trying to get an array of data from table, characters have invalid charset. With one field all is ok.

Here is my freetds.conf

```
[global]
tds version = 8.0
client charset = UTF-8
text size = 20971520
```

And laravel database config

```
'sqlsrv' => array(
        'driver'   => 'sqlsrv',
        'host'     => 'some-ip\DB',
        'database' => 'DBTEST',
        'username' => 'web-testUser',
        'password' => 'hereIsMyPassword',
        'charset'   => 'utf8',
        'prefix'   => '',
    ),
```

And simple function to get an array of data

```
Route::get('/', function()
{
    return var_dump(User::all()); //if i'll try to simple return data without using var_dump it'll crash
});
```